# how to get data based on parameter from oracle to EF

Tags: oracle, entity-framework, stored-procedures, odac

I have to make up to 100 reports based on data that  I have to retrieve from oracle providing some parameters to procedures/functions.
Now I am using ODAC and VS2010 to connect to oracle but I have a problem to create a FUNCTION IMPORT from either procedure(with sys_refcursor parameter) or function returning a table.

What is your way of doing this in the most easy way?

I don't want to go back to ADO and untyped data or datasets.
The possible solutions can be upgrading to newer version odac/vs using some other pattern of retrieving data from functions/procedures or setting up EF in a different way.

Comment: Not entirely sure what you are asking, but EF does [stored procedures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg699321.aspx) too:

Comment: mcalex - yes I can call oracle procedure and pass parameters, but how can I retrieve data and get entities

Comment: did you see the bits under 'Defining Functions in the Model's Metadata' and 'Function Imports and Output Parameters' in the link?

Comment: its all about MSSQL and not ORACLE, do you mean that I should manualy write all mapping in EF satelite files? But what should I do with hundreds reports? It will be a great problem tu support that kind of development

Comment: EF works with oracle, that link is just a how to. This link has [EF with oracle](http://download.oracle.com/oll/obe/EntityFrameworkOBE/EntityFrameworkOBE.htm) and has SP info